# undefined method `start_with?' for false:FalseClass on rails generate -p

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a relative rails newbie. Using rbenv, ruby 2.7.2 and rails 6.1.0. I get this error whenever I try to use `rails generate scaffold user -p`

```
/home/james/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor/actions.rb:116:in `relative_to_original_destination_root': undefined method `start_with?' for false:FalseClass (NoMethodError)
```

It works okay without the `-p`, but I don't feel confident enough with rails to know if it is a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's indeed a bug from Rails 6.1, I submitted a [PR](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/41255) to fix it.